# How to solve "Error from the server while geocoding...." in React native?

Tags: react-native, google-api, google-geocoder

I am getting this error when getting address using Geocoder in react native:

> Object {
>     "code": 4,
>     "message": "Error from the server while geocoding. The received datas are in the error's 'origin' field. Check it for more informations.",
>     "origin": Object {
>       "results": Array [],
>       "status": "ZERO_RESULTS",
>     },
>   }

I am using "react-native-geocoding" dependency

My code include in here:

```
Geocoder.init(GOOGLE_API_KEY); //google api key
Geocoder.from(latitude,longitude)
.then(json => {
  var addressComponent = json.results[0].address_components;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(addressComponent));      
})
.catch(error => console.warn(error));
```

Need some help?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found the solution?

Comment: Could you show the rest of your code, where is 'GOOGLE_API_KEY' declared?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by changing the google API key.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have fixed this by now but I also recently experienced the same error.

My issue had to do with how I was passing the coordinates to the Geocoder.from() function. I was passing them as strings. You need to cast them to a float first.

More information here: https://github.com/marlove/react-native-geocoding/issues/44

You can convert string coordinates to floats like so:

```
const latitude = parseFloat(coordinatesArray[0])
const longitude = parseFloat(coordinatesArray[1])
```